# Empty JSON response doesn't trigger error in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I am using Jackson to interpret JSON responses from an API that I am writing. I would like, as a standard throughout my API, to throw errors from the API to the program with something like:

```
{"errorMessage":"No such username."}
```

So I want my response processor to first check if the response is just a single errorMessage key, and if  so to handle the error, and if not, then to interpret it as whatever response it was expecting from that command.

So here's my code:

```
public class ProcessingException extends Exception {
    private String errorMessage;
    public ProcessingException(){}

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

}
```

and then, in my response handler:

```
@Override
public void useResponse(InputStream in) throws IOException, ProcessingException {
    // turn response into a string
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String response = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";

    ProcessingException exception;
    try {
        // Attempt to interpret as an exception
        exception = mapper.readValue(response, ProcessingException.class);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        // Otherwise interpret it as expected. responseType() is an abstract TypeReference
        // which is filled in by subclasses. useResponse() is also abstract. Each subclass
        // represents a different kind of request.
        Object responseObj = mapper.readValue(response, responseType());
        useResponse(responseObj);
        return;
    }
    // I needed this out of the try/catch clause because listener.errorResponse might
    // actually choose to throw the passed exception to be dealt with by a higher
    // authority.
    if (listener!=null) listener.errorResponse(exception);
}
```

This works beautifully, except under one circumstance - there are some requests that actually don't need to respond with anything, so they return `{}`. For some reason, this response completely runs through the `exception = mapper.readValue(response, ProcessingException.class);` line without triggering an IOException, so the program things that there is an error. But then when it tries to read what the error was, it throws a `NullPointerException` when trying to read `exception.getErrorMessage()`, because of course there is no error.

Why is it treating `{}` as a valid `ProcessingException` object?

Comment: Thinking out loud to myself - maybe it thinks that the empty constructor is a valid way to build a response?

Comment: Why don't you use status codes to indicate when there was an error on the request? As an example, returning 400 would indicate that the response message should be treated as an `ProcessingException`.

Comment: And yes, @clum is right. A json with no properties is definitely a valid way to construct a `ProcessingException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson doesn't have bean validation. But what you can do is to declare constructor as a JsonCreator that will be used to instantiate the new object and check/throw an exception in case if that field is null:

```
class ProcessingException  {
    private String errorMessage;

    @JsonCreator
    public ProcessingException(@JsonProperty("errorMessage") String errorMessage) {
        if (errorMessage == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'errorMessage' can't be null");
        }
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
    // getters, setters and other methods
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, many frameworks allow use of Bean Validation API implementation right after initial data-binding; `DropWizard`, for one.

Comment: @StaxMan you can use BeanValidation API where you want but you have to handle all the errors in your code. That is why it would be great to have Jackson integrated with Validation API and as far as I know it is in theirs plans.